# How can I filter emails sent to multiple recipients from a specific address?

Tags: gmail

I'm on some mailing list for a volunteer group and the coordinator constantly sends out nag emails.  Without being off-putting to her and trying to get my name axed from it, can I just filter all those emails?  This person uses *cc* for mailing lists rather than *bcc* so it seems do-able.  I do occasionally (rarely) get relevant email sent just to me, so I don't simply want to filter everything from her.

How can I set up a Gmail filter that catches everything where I'm not the sole recipient?

Answer (score 2):

Try searching `from:coordinator cc:me`. If that search turns up the results you expect, you can use it to filter those messages to skip the inbox and add a label.

Answer (score 1):

The best filter you can create is for the following query: `from:(coordinator) to:(volunteer1, volunteer2)` where `coorinator` is her email and `volunteer1` and `volunteer2` are emails of people who are only on this list. This way you'll avoid filtering out anything else.

Comment: What if the list changes?

Comment: Then you'll have to update the filter. Unfortunately, GMail doesn't have an operator for multiple recipients (i.e. "me and others").

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering on `deliveredto:your_email_address@example.com`, that worked for me.